# How to to restrict method resolution to only one parent in python multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

Lets say I have,

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        print("The parent class is A")
    def methodA(self):
        print("This method should only be accessed by a child of class A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        print("The parent class is B")
    def methodB(self):
        print("This method should only be accessed by a child of class B")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, var):
        # if var=='a':
        #     make this class the child of only class A
        #     i.e. it should only access methods of class A
        #     and forget methods of class B.
        # if var=='b':
        #     make this class the child class B
        #     i.e. it should only access methods of class B
        #     and forget methods of class A.
        pass
```

How can I achieve this? Precisely speaking I want to make a class that is derived from two classes but depending on the input parameter I want to disable one of the classes and use the attributes of only the other class. 
So that I get this,

```
>>> c = C('a')
>>> c.methodA()
This method should only be accessed by a child of class A
>>> c.methodB()
# A not implemented error or a maybe a custom error message.
```

Comment: Apart redefining both methods in C, i don't see a good way to do so. The question is more why would you want to do this.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Are you sure you wouldn't rather have, say, a factory function that returns either an `A` instance or a `B` instance? Inheritance isn't always the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this I would recommend a factory approach as suggested by user2357112 in the comments:

```
def C(parameter):
    if parameter == "a":
        return(A())
    else:
        return(B())
```

Of course these are not subclasses, so if you want to add methods/attributes to it you would need a bit more magic. You could probably implement that via metaclasses.